# In Django Admin, can I display a listing of an unrelated record set alongside an admin form?

Tags: django, django-admin

My use case is to implement something like a messaging form, allowing an administrator to write a message, then send it to group that they will filter from a list of users, from the User model. This is similar to the messaging to usergroups functionality in Joomla! so it's not too weird a use case.

So my admin page for the "Message" model would need to contain the Message creation form and a second recordset of site Users, which could be filtered down to those who the administrator wishes to contact.

Is this kind of thing possible in Django Admin, or do I need to dip into heavily customising an admin page?

Comment: Sure - just have a `Message.users` m2m field that's linked to the `User` class. It's not really a second recordset - it's just a many-to-many relation. From what you've described, you should be able to achieve this from just within the model admin class.